# How to put csrf_token inside django form view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, csrf

I am new in django and have faced a strange problem. If I create django template and insert {% csrf_token %} inside, it works well, but if I put @csrf_protect decorator to view, it gives me Forbidden 403 (CSRF verification failed. Request aborted). As I understand from django documentation, I can`t use both CsrfViewMiddleware and @csrf_protect.

So here is the question:

Is it possible to do csrf verification inside a view or should I always write templates in such situations?

```
@csrf_protect 
def create_group(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Group.objects.create(**{key: request.POST[key] for key in request.POST})
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("groups:groups"))
    elif request.method == "GET":
        pass
    return HttpResponse(create_group_form)
```

```
create_group_form = """
    <form method="POST">
      <label for="course">Course:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="course" name="course"><br><br>
      <label for="length_in_months">Length in months:</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="length_in_months" name="length_in_months" min=1 max=12 required><br><br>
      <label for="price">Price:</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="price" name="price" min=1000 max=50000 required><br><br>
      <label for="number_of_students">Number of students:</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="number_of_students" name="number_of_students" min=3 max=30 required><br><br>
      <label for="lesson_duration">Lesson duration:</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="lesson_duration" name="lesson_duration" min=1 max=5 required><br><br>
      <label for="website">Website:</label><br>
      <input type="url" id="website" name="website"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> """
```

Comment: Are you still using the the  `{% csrf_token %}` in your form? The `CsrfViewMiddleware` and the `@csrf_protect` decorators are both providing the context variable, but you still need to use it in your form.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `CsrfViewMiddleware` as an overall protection. If you forget to add the decorator to your views, it'll create security issues. You must use it on the views that assign `CSRF tokens` to the output and the ones that accept data from the `POST` form. So, as the best practice its better to use `CSRF token` in template unless we have a specific requirement.